# Firebase Push Notification in Flutter when App Kiled

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, push-notification, notifications

I'm having an issue dealing with Firebase push notifications when the App is *KILLED*.
What's happening:
First of all, push notifications should work like this. When you tap, you are redirected to a Move-Type Job or an Event-Type Job.

- When app is in ***BACKGROUND MODE***, push notification shows as it should,
  and it redirects to the page that it should.
- When App is ***KILLED***, push notifications still shows, but when you tap on them you are not redirected, you are just opening the App.

```html
Future initialize() async {
    await getConnectivity();
    if (hasInternet) {
      try {
        await configurePushNotificationHandlers();
      } catch (e) {
        hasApiConnection = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
Future configurePushNotificationHandlers() async {
    await navigationService.navigateReplacementWithParams(ErrorPage());

    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    String fbToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      if (message.data != null && message.data.containsKey('showInPageNotification')) {
        numberOfNotifications++;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      if (message.data != null && message.data.containsKey('job_id')) {
        String jobId = message.data['job_id'];
        String jobType = message.data['job_type'];

        jobType = jobType.toLowerCase();

        if (jobType == 'move') {
          await goToJobDetail(jobId);
        } else {
          await goToEventDetail(jobId);
        }
      }
    });
```

Anyone has a clue of why does this happens? Push notifications are working fine, it's the redirection the current ISSUE. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code snippets?

Comment: I added to the post the page where I have the notification handlers configuration, when I run this Widget it runs the initialize and that method @OzanTaskiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() method to get messages

If App is Closed/Killed

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .getInitialMessage()
          .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage $message");
   });
```

**Try this and let me know.**